# How do i change the way contacts display?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My contacts are in list form but my favorites are a thumbnail with a picture, etc. How do I get my contacts to change to this display?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't supported by default in the stock Contacts provider. However, you can use a third party contact management application that allows thumbnail view. One good option would be [Contacts+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android).